# How to make the word "Reference " bold while keeping the desired font

Tags: bibtex

I want all section titles to be bold while keeping the desired font. However, the word "Reference" is automatically added when using the following codes and is ***NOT*** bold. How to change this, please? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[english,  bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\title{The Law of Iterated Logarithm}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction, Definitions and Notations}
\section{Proof of the Hartman-Wintner Theorem (Two Special Cases)}
\subsection{Outline of Proof}
\subsection{Case One: Standard Linear Brownian Motion}
\subsection{Case Two: Simple Random Walk}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}` is to blame. Please change `\rm` to `\textrm{...}`, since `\rm` is deprecated for 20 years now

Comment: The title is bold, if you remove `\setkomafont{disposition}...`

Comment: Replace `\normalfont` with `\bfseries`, but I don't understand your question any longer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, your question is not very clear. For that reason, I doubt very much that this will answer it. However, it is too long for a comment and perhaps it will help you to clarify your question. (At that point, I can change or delete this answer as appropriate.)

I've tidied up your MWE a bit so that it includes some stuff necessary to actually produce a bibliography and includes less that is irrelevant to the question. When I do that and remove the command which tells the class to use `\normalfont` for the section titles, I get the default bold titles throughout:

[image: default bold titles with Koma]

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{article,
    title   =   {Title},
    author  =   {Author, A. N.},
    year    =   1962,
    journal =   {Journal},
    pages   =   {33-76},
    volume  =   2,
    number  =   5}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  \title{The Law of Iterated Logarithm}
  \date{\today}
  \maketitle

  \tableofcontents
  \section{Introduction, Definitions and Notations}
  \section{Proof of the Hartman-Wintner Theorem (Two Special Cases)}
  \subsection{Outline of Proof}
  \subsection{Case One: Standard Linear Brownian Motion}
  \subsection{Case Two: Simple Random Walk}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

It may be that the reason you issued `\normalfont` was to avoid the titles being typeset in a *sans* font. If so, you might want to try this line:

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
```

[image: norally sized bold serif section titles]